# The argument type 'Userr? Function(User?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'User Function(User?)'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```dart
import 'package:brew_crew/models/user.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Userr? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
    return user != null ? Userr(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  Stream<User?> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebaseUser);
  }

  Future signInAnon() async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      User? user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user!);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have written double rr in the function return type remove the one r

```
User? _userFromFirebaseUser(User? user) {
return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
}
```

Comment: Consider userr as MyUser it is a class MyUser {
  final String uid;
  MyUser({required this.uid});
}